# The name 'model' does not exist in the current context in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core

I'm writing some application in Asp.Net Core and I have some problem with View.

My controller return Dictionary to the view:

```
Dictionary<string, List<MyModel>>
```

and in my View I have:

```
@model System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, List<MyProject.Folder1.MyModel>
```

and when I would like to iterate by foreach

```
    @foreach (var blog in Model)
{
//code
}
```

I have got an error:

> The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Do you have any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Comment: Your code looks totally fine.

Comment: @mason in Line  '@'foreach (var blog in Model). You know what, I put my dictionary to the another class e.g MyClass and it's work well, but I still would like to know why I can't use dictorary directly on the view page

Comment: That error *cannot* exist at that line. It's case sensitive. `@foreach (var blog in Model)` would not give you the error `The name 'model' does not exist in the current context`. So either you posted your error or your code incorrectly in your question.

Comment: I have identical error, so it can, somehow

Comment: This error happened to me after upgrading from project.json to VS17 style csproj. My project was importing Microsoft.NET.Sdk instead of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't that be something like

```
@foreach (var blog in Model["somekey"] as List<MyModel>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Class:**

```
public class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
        Dictionary<string, List<Class1>> myDict = new Dictionary<string, List<Class1>>();
        List<Class1> objList = new List<Class1>();
        Class1 objClass=new Class1();
        objClass.Id=1;
        objClass.Name="Sandip";
        objList.Add(objClass);
        myDict.Add("sandip", objList);
        return View(myDict);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model Dictionary<string, List<MyMvcApplication.Models.Class1>>
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Index";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@foreach (var kvp in Model)
{
     //logic
}
```